# Why serving static files are an issue in Python apps

Tags: python, django, static, hosting, whitenoise

I don't seem to understand the issue with serving static files in Python apps, for example Django. Now I am reading a documentation of WhiteNoise and first question is why it was developed in the first place? I mean what problem it solves? Why we can't save all the static files in /static folder and copy it to hosting.

Comment: You can, but then you should configure Apache/nginx/other webserver to serve these files. Django by default does not serve static/media files, because it will likely be slower, and less secure.

Comment: Django server was not developed with a view of serving static files

Answer (score 3):

> I don't seem to understand the issue with serving static files in Python apps, for example Django.

As is specified in the [Django documentation on *managing static files*](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/static-files/#configuring-static-files):

> This method is **grossly inefficient** and probably **insecure**, so it is unsuitable for production.

Indeed, Django's views to serve static files are likely not very efficient. A webserver will typically cache a certain amount of files, use compression to send these to the browser (if the browser accepts this), etc. Django's views to serve static/media files are not designed to be competitive with a webserver like *apache/nginx*.

Even if that is solved, it using a signle server to serve static content is not a good idea. Often **C**ontent **D**elivery **N**etworks (CDNs) are used to find a server close to the client that can serve these files.

The Django documentation therefore contains articles to [deploy static files on a dedicated server](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/static-files/deployment/#serving-static-files-from-a-dedicated-server) and how to [configure this server](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/#serving-files).

The whitenoise package is simply a best effort attempt to serve these files with a Python view. Python is more designed to reduce programmer time, not processing time, so while whitenoise is efficient, very likely it can not compete with CDN.